# how to create role in mongodb with limited permission like find,insert,update and deleteOne?

Tags: mongodb

I just installed MongoDB using ubuntu 16.04, I have created a standard user with limited permission (actions) but I do not want to give remove permission to roles but I want to allow only find, insert, update and deleteOne action to the roles, Suggest me what I need to do for that?

Comment: What specific version of MongoDB server are you using? What roles/privileges have you already granted? You could create a custom role with applicable [`readWrite` privileges](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#readWrite), but there is no separate permission for `deleteOne`. The `deleteOne` and `deleteMany` commands both call the same `delete` command (which requires `remove` privilege).

Comment: I am using MongoDB 4.0.6, thanks for the reply, I just did that, as per your steps.